# UNEXPECTED EOF encountered in bcp data file

Tags: database, linux

This question has been asked sometimes before by other. But i did not get my answer.
Hope you will help me with this.

I have large BCP file with more than 3000 rows.
When it is copied with options -c -t| -r\n it fails at line number 2967 saying UNEXPECTED EOF encountered in bcp data file.

If i see that line through od -bc and compare to the previous line i see not much of difference.
When i tried to load the file in a different enviroment (Testing) with option as below:
-c -t\| -r\n..it runs fine.

Could someone please advise me on how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I opened the file in notepad++. and changed the encoding to `UCS-2 Little endian`. And it worked for me.
 UCS-2 Little Endian encoding is what SQL Server expects as default encoding,